# Excel hyperlinks.add anchor syntax/argument

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Below is a bit of code I'm using to track changes to an excel doc. I get a runtime error '5' "Invalid procedure call or argument" on the bolded bit. I think the issue is the syntax or arguments for the Hyperlinks.Add anchor, since 'anchor' doesn't capitalize when I go to the next line. Do I have the arguments and the syntax correct?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
 sSheetName = "1107"

If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Target.Address(0, 0)
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = OldValue
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Now
 **Sheets("LogDetails").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sSheetName & "'!" & OldAddress, TextToDisplay:=OldAddress**


 Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: What is `OldAddress`?, string, range?

Comment: It's a string...

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the apostrophes when setting the `SubAddress`

Example recorded with Excel:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "Sheet1!A1", TextToDisplay:="Sheet1!A1df"
```

Code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

With Excel.Application
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim sSheetName As String
    sSheetName = "1107"

    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then

        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & Target.Address(0, 0)
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = OldValue
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Now

        Dim hlink_cell As Range
        Set hlink_cell = Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5)

        Sheets("LogDetails").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=hlink_cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=sSheetName & "!" & OldAddress, TextToDisplay:=OldAddress

        Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit

    End If

With Excel.Application
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```